# Laravel + Leaflet for Post Code Density Map

Tags: laravel, leaflet, geojson

I would appreciate some help if possible. I have no idea where to start - I am just starting to play with Leaflet.

I have a MySQL table as part of my Laravel application. Within this table, is a column `postcode`.

I have a large GeoJSON file which contains all the post code polygons.

I am looking to generate a density map with colours and labels and render this based on values from my database.

So the end result is a colourful map, with all the GeoJSON polygons representing the post code areas including those with a count of 0.

I appreciate your time!
P.s - I am open to other mapping visualisation tools instead of Leaflet.